# Laravel 5 $user->first()->delete() deleting all users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I use `$user->where('id', $id)->first()->delete()` in Laravel 5.1 it seems to delete ALL users.

Is this the expected functionality?

Comment: An ID is supposed to be unique and should delete at most only one user. If there are more than one user, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Do you get the same result for `$user->find($id)->delete()`?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - even if there are multiple users with the same id, the code provided in the OP would still only delete one of them.

Comment: I think it's a problem with the model relationships I have setup.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong.
if you want to delete the first row in a model

```
$user-> first()->delete();
```

if you want to delete a model by id

```
$id = 5;
$user -> where('id',$id) -> delete();// it will delete row 5 from the table
$user::find($id) -> delete();
$user = User::find($id);
$user -> delete();
```

you can also use

```
$user -> destroy(1,2,3); // will delete row 1,2 and 3.
```

Hope this help.